# @Security Symfony annotation denies access - but states lack of authentication

Tags: symfony

Here's my annotation:

```
@Security("
    request.getHost() == 'example.com' or
    request.getHost() == 'google.com'
 ")
```

This works, but throws the following error:

`Full authentication is required to access this resource.`

This results in a 500 rather than a 403 as expected. The debug log:

```
DEBUG - Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point.
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InsufficientAuthenticationException: "Full authentication is required to access this resource." at /[path]/[to]/[project]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php line 131
```

But there's no authentication point setup (or that needs to be setup):

`security.yml`:

```
 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt))/
        security: false

    no_auth:
        pattern: ^/(|css|images|js|admin/login)/
        security: false

    admin:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/admin
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - admin.form_login
        logout:
            path: admin_logout

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/
```

The annotation is on a controller that exists in `^/`.

**How do I get Symfony to throw a simple Access Denied?**

When I do this on my admin controller, it behaves as expected - I don't get the lack of authentication, I get access denied. However, I need to have an unauthenticated resource, but limited by IP.